# Stripe-java client does not delete plans while curl does

Tags: java, stripe-payments

I am trying to delete a plan programmatically using the Stripe java client. The delete operation using the java client does nothing. The delete operation using curl works.

stripe-java version

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.stripe</groupId>
      <artifactId>stripe-java</artifactId>
      <version>10.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

#### Java

```java
      final PlanCollection plans = Plan.list(new HashMap<>());
      List<Plan> planList = plans.getData();

      for (Plan plan: planList) {
        plan.delete();
      }
```

I verified that valid **Plan** objects are retrieved and present in the **planList**.

#### Curl

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/plans/plan_xxxx -u sk_test_xxxx: -X DELETE
```

This succeeds and I verified that the deleted plan no longer exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally, [`delete()`](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/stripe/model/Plan.java) uses `plan.getId()` to build the request URL, so you could also make sure that ID is populated.

The other aspect I would verify is that the API Key you are specifying in `Stripe.apiKey` is the same that you are using with cURL.

Finally, `delete()` and `list()` methods might throw `StripeException` in their signatures, which is a checked Exception and hence your code must be handling it. Make sure you are not getting any exception, and if so, you should revise how you are handling them - the answer must be there :).

Comment: The root cause for my issue was a very silly mistake on my part. I did not realize that Plan.list(new HashMap<>()).getData() only returns the first page of plans, and the default page size is 10. Since I had way more than 10 plans, I thought the delete operations were not working in some of my tests when saw that there were still only 10 plans after the delete operation. Fix is to use autoPagingIterable() to get all the plans. I will still mark this answer as accepted since you gave a good list of things to check that would be helpful to people in most cases.